# Php & Mysqli query with dynamic variable not working. Trying to replace "?" in query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

The code below makes a query and then loops through those results. I am having a hard time understanding what "?" is in that query and how to make "?" dynamic.

It assume that name = "?". I have changed ? to a variable I added in the function $ad_id and that still does not work. I basically need to query the DB only WHERE name = a variable. But this simple solution does not work. The commented line is what I replaced.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Incase you are wondering this is the code I am trying to make dynamic and not just pulling all images in the table:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration

```
protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
        parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
            $ad_id = '1';
            //$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description` FROM `'
                //.$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
            $sql = 'SELECT id, type, title, description FROM '.$this->options['db_table'].' WHERE name = '.'$ad-id'.';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('s', $file->name);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result(
                $id,
                $type,
                $title,
                $description
            );
            while ($query->fetch()) {
                if ($description == $ad_id){
                    $file->id = $id;
                    $file->type = $type;
                    $file->title = $title;
                    $file->description = $description;
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the SQL query is using bound parameters. This means that you create the string for the SQL query, and put a placeholder in for each variable - the placeholder is the '?' character you mentioned. Then the following two lines:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('s', $file->name);
```

The first line sends the query to the database, and the second line sends the parameters that need to be bound into the placeholder sites (where those question marks were in the query string). So if you want to change the variable that is inserted into the query, you should change the bind_param call.

Check out the documentation for `bind_param`, but basically the 's' specifies a string parameter, and the second argument is the variable itself.

Hopefully that gives you enough insight into what is going on here to change the code to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks I will check out the docs for it. I changed that parameter to a dynamic, static and global variable and was still getting errors. Maybe I am missing something else. But thanks I will look into the docs again.